# Can't get data from postgresql database using knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm struggling with dealing with a knex connections. I want to get some data from my pg db but all it does it's returning my select, not the actual data that I expect to get.
[This is what I do in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4gMo.png)
[And this is my knex connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khi0A.png)

I've tried googling it, but I can't find the proper instructions on it. Please, tell me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working example with `postgres` without any framework

```
import knex from 'knex'
import configuration from './knexfile.js'

const connection = knex(configuration.development)

const res = await connection.from('tablename').select('id', 'content')

for (const row of res) {
  console.log(`id: ${row.id}, content: ${row.content}`)
}
```

Inside of file `knexfile.js` you need the config created by command `npx knex init`